# Placing @Column on field and @Transient on getter and setter at once

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

Please, explain for what purpose @Transient was placed on getter and setter methods at the same time as @Column was placed on field. 
The field is stored to DB as we need.

```java
@Entity

@Table(name = "person")

public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name; 

    @Transient
    public long getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Transient
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code as you have it, they have no effect, since the @Id on a field causes the default access to be field, thus ignoring any method annotations. If property access was the default (either by @Id on the getter or @Access(PROPERTY) on the class), the @Transient annotations would cause JPA to ignore the accessors, presumably so that the field mapping could be picked up. However, in that case, the field should be annotated with @Access(FIELD).

I'd say the @Transient annotations are leftovers from a time when the entity had default property access.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a tricky situation. `@transient` annotation and `transient` keyword doesn't provide same functionality. using `transient` keyword will not serialize your data. but using `@transient` annotation will serialize the data but will not be `persisted` in the database, since you have marked the field with `@column` annotation that field will be `persisted` in the database because `@Column` allows you to specify the name of the column in the database to which the attribute is to be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its ignored since the column is marked already and as you say it is being updated as required. Enabling logging would confirm this as it would generate a warning

You could do a test creating a new test field and marking the getter/setter as Transient